# SimpleCMS, PageLime. Are they secure?

Tags: content-management-system

I have a medium size site (50 pages) with about half the pages being static.  I would like to give my client access to edit the static pages and was considering either PageLime or SimpleCMS.  But, security is a concern for my client.  Can anyone comment on the security of either of these CMS's?  I'm a little concerned as well, because the site's FTP credentials are stored on the CMS's site.

Thanks for any input.